# What are the Void() and PollAsync() methods of IDialogTask for?

Tags: c#, botframework

I'm following the instructions posted [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/core-GlobalMessageHandlers) to create a global handler for my bot. In reaction to certain keywords ("help"), I'd like to forward to a dialog by using:

```
var replyDialog = new CommonResponsesDialog($"Sometimes I also feel **{state}**...");
var interruption = replyDialog.Void<object, IMessageActivity>();
_task.Call(interruption, null);
await _task.PollAsync(token);
```

Two things are unclear:

- What is `replyDialog.Void<object, IMessageActivity>();` doing? Even after reading the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.dialogs.chain.void?view=botbuilder-3.8#Microsoft_Bot_Builder_Dialogs_Chain_Void__2_Microsoft_Bot_Builder_Dialogs_IDialog___0__) I don't understand it. Why can't I push the `replyDialog` directly?
- What is `await _task.PollAsync(token);` for?

Comment: Shouldn't the parameter be `IAwaitable<IMessageActivity>` instead of `IAwaitable<object>`?

Comment: Does not matter but the problem is/was something else. I have to change my question...

Comment: Did you read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.dialogs.chain.void?view=botbuilder-3.8#Microsoft_Bot_Builder_Dialogs_Chain_Void__2_Microsoft_Bot_Builder_Dialogs_IDialog___0__): *The purpose of this method is to wrap an antecedent dialog A with a new dialog D to push on the stack on top of the existing stack top dialog L.*

Comment: I did but it does not make a lot of sense to me. Why would I wrap A with D to push it on L? What is A in my case? What is D? What is L? Why not just push "A" (I suppose that's my `replyDialog`) on the stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `Void` is to wrap the `replyDialog` with an additional dialog that will be in charge of restarting the wait for messages from the user once the child dialog (your `replyDialog`) has finished.

The `.Call` puts the interrupting dialog on the stack and the `.PollAsync` starts running the interrupting dialog.

If you review the `VoidDialog<T,R>` class ([here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Dialogs/Chain.cs#L758)), you will see that:

1. As soon as it starts, it calls the "antecedent" dialog
2. Once the antecedent dialog has finished, ignores the result and waits for new user messages
3. After a new message is received, it will end the `VoidDialog` passing the message to the original dialog.